# Highcharts ajax loaded tool tip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have a high chart on my web page which is plotting the interval data of no. of tweets vs time and it is working perfectly fine, but what i want is the tool tip to show the top tweet of that time, for that i need to make an Ajax call every time the charts pops up an tool tip.

But i am not getting how to make an Ajax call in high charts tool tip (a simple get request), and how to cache it so that it doesn't make the same request again and again on the same x-axis point.

Also there is no proper reference available for this question on internet..

Comment: You can set tooltipFormatter, but for me, you will have many request to your server, so consider better solution. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the tool tip that shows up when hovering over the chart you can set this when setting up the chart by using

```
tooltip:
{
  formatter: function()
  {
    return (/some html that returns what you want/);
  }
},
```

Also you can interact with the chart after it's loaded by doing the following:

```
var chart = $('#name-of-your-chart-div').highcharts();
```

Hope i've understood your question correctly.

Also a great place to look is the Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts